# Unit Testing with Firebase (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Trying to do some simple unit testing with Firebase, but for some reason Firestore won't initialize:

ModelTests.swift:

```
func testFirebase() throws
{
    // THIS IS ALWAYS "UNINITIALIZED"
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    // Because db isn't initialized correctly, this ref will always be nil.
    let ref: DocumentReference? = db.document("unit_testing/xxx")
    ref?.setData([
        "id" : "someID",
        "name" : "goldenjoe",
        "another" : "bmus",
        "testDate" : Date()
        ],
                 merge: true,
                 completion: { err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                    }
                }
        )
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool 
{
    // Set up Firestore
    FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyWork' do
use_frameworks!

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# Pods for MyWork
pod 'CoreXLSX'
pod 'Eureka'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'ProgressHUD'
#pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'SteviaLayout'

target 'MyWorkTests' do
  inherit! :complete
  end

end
```

However, when I run the app normally, I can use Firebase just fine in other parts of the app. Can't find anything online about a special configuration being needed for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, can't say what the specific configuration problem was, but this ended up being one of those "try turning it off and on again" solutions.

```
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
pod install
```

Also, in direct opposition to the documentation, you DO need to include `Firebase/Core` in your podfile, otherwise you won't be able to initialize Firestore.